# std::list erasing (free memory)

Tags: c++, performance, destructor, stdlist

```
struct SomeStruct
{
};

class C
{
public:

    C()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
        {
            m_List.push_back(new SomeStruct);
        }
    }

private:

    std::list<SomeStruct*> m_List;
};
```

Which of two variants of destructor faster (why?) for freeing memory:

```
~C()
{
    for (auto iter = m_List.begin(); iter != m_List.end(); ++iter)
    {
        delete *iter;
    }
}


~C()
{
    while (m_List.size() != 0)
    {
        delete *m_List.begin();

        m_List.pop_front();
    }
}
```

Comment: Those raw pointers are very problematic. I would suggest just `SomeStruct` until proven you need a pointer, and then use a smart pointer.

Comment: chris, I know about smart pointers, this question is not about how to store pointers, I only wanna you to choose one of destructors and explain why you choose it.

Comment: @Edward83:  I didn't downvote, but I can think of a couple of reasons why someone might.  You are using raw pointers.  People often downvote what they view as generally *bad code*, and in my book, that's what this is.  You are asking *us* about the performance difference between two snippets of code, where what you *should* be doing is testing it yourself.

Comment: Another reason, you are asking "which is faster" when there is no evidence whatsoever that you have profiled your code and determined that this is a bottleneck that needs to be micro-optimized.  Premature micro-optimization is the root of all evil, yada yada.

Comment: I really doubt the performance difference matters for anything, and it's invalidated by the fact that this code shouldn't be used in the first place. If you're that worried about performance, you'd initialize the list with `(100, new SomeStruct)` instead of an explicit loop of `push_back`s.

Comment: about profiling you right - I am lazy:)

Comment: If you're worried about performance, then the best optimisation would be to remove the unnecessary level of indirection (and with it the need for an explicit destructor) by storing objects. Unless your real code actually needs to store pointers, for polymorphism or whatever, in which case the answer can only come from your profiler.

Comment: Why `std::list<SomeStruct*>` rather than `std::vector<SomeStruct>`?

Comment: @chris That would result in 100 entries all pointing to the same dynamically allocated object, rather than 100 different allocated objects.

Comment: @JamesKanze, Right, I forgot the rest are copy-constructed. Now there's an accident waiting to happen.

Comment: The performance overhead for free-store management dwarfs the required time for either of the two variants, so Chris' initial objection is exactly on the spot. If you're asked in an interview, giving either answer is wrong, it checks whether you're able to think outside the box.

Answer (score 1):

First one is faster. Second one is deleting the head and removing it as well. You don't need to remove the list elements explicitly. The complete list is anyway be destroyed as it is member of C

Comment: The first one will also (implicitly) erase all the elements of the list. What evidence do you have that that will be faster than doing it explicitly?

Comment: Iterating the list twice puts more stress on your CPU's cache/memory bandwidth. Also, just wondering, isn't it possible for a conforming implementation to have an O(n) implementation of `size()`?